# Swfit error Cannot find 'hexIntToStr' in scope

Tags: swift

Have been unable to find the error
「Cannot find 'hexIntToStr' in scope」

```
func bytesToStr(bytes: [UInt8]) -> String {
        var hexStr = ""
        for index in 0 ..< bytes.count {
            var str = bytes[index].description
            if str.count == 1 {
                str = "0" + str
            } else {
                let low = Int(str)! % 16
                let hight = Int(str)! / 16
                str = hexIntToStr(hexInt: hight) + hexIntToStr(hexInt: low)
            }
            hexStr += str
        }
        return hexStr
 }
```

Comment: Did you write such a function? If you didn't, I don't know what else you expected.

Comment: I refer to the examples on the Internet and practice
https://www.mephisto.site/posts/iOS-NFC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code on the mentioned site is just incomplete, the method `hexIntToStr`  is missing.

But it's a very simple method, here it is

```
func hexIntToStr(hexInt: Int) -> String {
    String(hexInt, radix: 16)
}
```

---

Side note:

The code to convert bytes to a hex string is very cumbersome. In Swift there are more convenient and efficient ways.

This is "Hello" in `UInt8` bytes

```
let bytes : [UInt8] = [0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f]
```

One way is to convert the `UInt8` array to `Data` and `map` the bytes with `String(format:)` specifying the hex format `"%02hhx"` and finally `join` the twin characters.

```
let hexString = Data(bytes).map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined() 
// 48656c6c6f
```

the letters a-f are lowercase, a capital `X` at the end of the format produces uppercase letters

```
// 48656C6C6F
```

---

Another way is to `reduce` the `Data` by splitting each byte in two nibbles with bit shifting and convert it with the `String(_:radix:)` method already being used in `hexIntToStr`

```
let hexString = Data(bytes).reduce(into:"") { result, byte in
    result.append(String(byte >> 4, radix: 16))
    result.append(String(byte & 0x0f, radix: 16))
}
```